# Define files which should not be merged by Perforce

Tags: perforce

I am trying to merge with perforce the entire content from another branch (source and target files or branch mapping), but I don't want to merge the files which are supposed to be auto-generated based on other files.

Is there some way to define a set of files which should be skipped from merge when doing a branch merge? I would like to reuse the solution multiple times and the maintenance overhead should be low if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up a branch mapping, see http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4guide/06_codemgmt.html.

If your generated files have some pattern that makes them easy to identify with a P4 file specification, or if they live in a small subset of folders, then it should be pretty easy to exclude them from your mapping.

Comment: Thanks. I think branch mapping should solve it, I've just noticed in the documentation there is a way to exclude mappings - "Mappings beginning with a hyphen (-) specifically exclude any files that match that mapping. "